# В каком виде в оперативной памяти хранятся генераторы?

Tags: python

В каком виде в оперативной памяти храниться генератор при итерации по нему?

Например:

```
res = (num for num in range(10**100000)
for el in res:
    print(el)
```

Понятно, что сам генератор храниться как объект в оперативной памяти и занимает некоторое определенное место. Но что происходит при непосредственной итерации по нему? Какую память начинает занимать сам генератор `res` после 1-ой, 2-ой и так далее итераций?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
res = (num for num in range(10**100000)
```

приблизительно соответствует следующему коду

```
def f():
    for num in range(10**100000)
        yield num

res = f()
```

Здесь `f` – это [сопрограмма](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0), специальная функция, которая приостанавливает выполнение после каждого `yield`, давая возможность вызывающей стороне забрать сгенерированное значение, а также передать какое-нибудь значение внутрь функции.

Сопрограмма возобновит выполнение с того места, где остановилась, когда вызывающая сторона попросит следующее значение. Если значений не осталось (сопрограмма завершилась), она выбросит исключение `StopIteration`, которое воспринимается как сигнал к завершению цикла.

```
def f():
    for i in range(3):
        x = yield i * i
        print('получено', x)
```

```
>>> coro = f()
>>> coro.send(None)
0
>>> coro.send(11)
получено 11
1
>>> coro.send(True)
получено True
4
>>> coro.send('test')
получено test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Другими словами, генераторное выражение хранится в виде вызванной, но не завершенной функции, и занимает примерно столько памяти, сколько требуется на хранение самого функционального объекта и всех локальных переменных вызванной функции.

С `range` дела обстоят немного иначе. Это объект, который хранит три значения – `начало`, `конец` и `шаг` и на их основе позволяет вычислить любое значение из диапазона по формуле

> r<sub>i</sub> = начало + i ∙ шаг

или

> r<sub>i</sub> = конец + i ∙ шаг

если индекс отрицательный.

А при взятии среза создается новый объект `range`

```
>>> r = range(0, 1000000, 1000)
>>> r[0]
0
>>> r[-1]
999000
>>> r[1:10]
range(1000, 10000, 1000)
>>> r[::-1]
range(999000, -1000, -1000)
```

Когда такой объект передается в `for`, создается итератор, который дополнительно хранит еще и индекс текущего элемента.

```
>>> r = range(3)
>>> it = iter(r)
>>> it
<range_iterator object at 0x7f5cb3a91ba0>
>>> next(it)
0
>>> next(it)
1
>>> next(it)
2
>>> next(it)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Т.е. `range`, так же как и генераторное выражение не нуждается в том, чтобы хранить все значения в памяти, он просто высчитывает очередное значение при каждом обращении

Answer (score 2):

Размер занимаемый генератором в памяти, не должен сильно меняться.

Пример:

```
In [119]: gen = (num for num in range(10**100000))

In [120]: sys.getsizeof(gen)
Out[120]: 88

In [121]: gen.__next__()
Out[121]: 0

In [122]: gen.__next__()
Out[122]: 1

In [123]: gen.__next__()
Out[123]: 2

In [124]: sys.getsizeof(gen)
Out[124]: 88

In [125]: for i in range(10000):
     ...:     gen.__next__()
     ...:

In [126]: sys.getsizeof(gen)
Out[126]: 88
```

Answer (score 1):

Генераторное выражение, это, по сути, просто итератор (то есть то, что идёт после `in`) плюс информация о том, что нужно сделать с очередным элементом (то есть часть `... for ...` и, если она есть, то ещё часть с `if`).

То есть когда от генератора требуется очередной элемент, ему нужно просто дернуть очередной элемент из итератора, проверить, что оно совпадает с условием `if` (если оно есть), и выполнить какую-то обработку, которая описана в `... for ...`.

Соответственно, никакой дополнительной памяти не нужно в процессе перебора элементов генератора.